# What is the difference between these two regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

What is the difference between these two regular expressions :

```
[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_=;.?]+[0-9]+
```

and

```
[a-zA-Z]+[!@#$%^&*()_=;.?][0-9]+
```

A token can start with multiple *alphabetical characters* and will end with *number sequence*. It can also start with *one special character* and will end with *number sequence*.

First regex breaks the string `jkl3242oij92384nji332332!23#900&6382^832983@7729.979797_70979797` into the desired tokens but second doesn't. Why ?

How do I implement the concept, that only one special character is allowed ?

Comment: If you want to explicitly say starts/ends with then you should anchors (`$` and `^`). Otherwise you might get unexpected results

Comment: @Dgrin91 A token should.Not the complete string.

Comment: Both fail to match the whole pattern, not only the second one: http://regex101.com/r/wH2dU3, http://regex101.com/r/jV6vG5

Comment: @kelunik NO. It matches https://www.debuggex.com/r/WXe7TvUNpTWFpSYM

Comment: @saplingPro yes, multible times, ok, but not the whole at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I got that right:

```
([a-zA-Z]+|[!@#$%^&*()_=;.?])[0-9]+
```

Starts with multiple alphanumerical or one special and ends with digits only.

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bW1iZ5)

Comment: what does the parenthesis `(` suggest ?

Comment: @saplingPro parenthesis have two purposes in regex, to group or to capture. In this case, it's helping us group with the "OR" (`|`) expression.

Comment: This is there in combination with pipe `|` to say: Well, either a-zA-Z OR a special character.

Comment: If I omit the pipe it splits but..that was not what I wanted

Comment: You should not omit the pipe, otherwise you're there, were your second regex in the question was.

Comment: I am sorry..I meant the parenthesis

Comment: @saplingPro You shouldn't omit the parenthesis either, why are you?

Comment: @Daemon because I don't understand, what is the need for parenthesis. Pipe is enough to join the logic and process as should be processed

Comment: @saplingPro The parenthesis groups the first two expressions. Using the parenthesis you're telling the state machine that you want either `[a-zA-Z]+` OR `[!@#$%^&*()_=;.?]` followed by `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that regex #1: `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_=;.?]+[0-9]+` will break a string into tokens of at least one of the characters: `[a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_=;.?]` followed by at least on number `[0-9]`.

Regex #2: `[a-zA-Z]+[!@#$%^&*()_=;.?][0-9]+` on the other hand, will break a string into tokens of at least one letter `[a-zA-Z]`, followed by **one** of `[!@#$%^&*()_=;.?]`, followed by at least one number `[0-9]`.

Comment: What should be my regular expression, so that only one special character is allowed ?

Comment: Your second regex is what you want, but it's nowhere in your posted token.

Comment: @saplingPro I don't fully understand your requirement. Can your token start with a special character **instead of** multiple letters?

Comment: @Daemon What do I do to achieve this ?

Comment: @saplingPro Oh ok, now I got that right, see my answer, it's still very early here ;)

Comment: @saplingPro You probably want something along the lines of `([!@#$%^&*()_=;.?]|[a-zA-Z]+)[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but I have found this a very useful tool to debug regular expressions:  https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Comment: @kelunik I agree, but for the life of me I couldn't find a way to add a comment.  Is it because I don't have a high enough reputation yet?  Or did I just miss it?

Comment: Oh yes, I see, you need at least 50 reputation, most useless limitation on SO.^^